# Screen resizing to fit with resolutions

Tags: css, html

I've uploaded the website mrandmrsmagic.com, whilst it looks fine when you have it maximized, minimized only half of it is shown (I took away the scroll bar because it shows up when it's maximized so perhaps there's something loose hanging about it.). The site itself, I used 5 different background images since I sliced them in Photoshop (It's been awhile since I built a site from ground up so the coding is probably pretty messy.) Below is the css of the 5 div's that I used for the body.

```
#body {
width: 1024px;
height: 583px;
marin: 0;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
left: 448px;
top: -128px;
background: url(../images/body_02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}

#body2 {
width: 1024px;
height: 583px;
position: relative;
left: 448px;
top: -128px;
background: url(../images/body2_02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}

#body3 {
width: 1024px;
height: 583px;
position: relative;
left: 448px;
top: -128px;
background: url(../images/body3_02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}

#body4 {
width: 1024px;
height: 583px;
position: relative;
left: 448px;
top: -128px;
background: url(../images/body4_02.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}

#body5 {
width: 1024px;
height: 583px;
position: relative;
left: 448px;
top: -128px;
background: url(../images/body5_02.jpg)  no-repeat left top;
}

#body6 {
width: 1024px;
height: 583px;
position: relative;
left: 448px;
top: -128px;
background: url(../images/body6_02.jpg)
}
```

I tried taking away the height and putting the width at 100%, but then it wasn't remedied and it almost made it worst. So is there a way to go about switching the css around, where I can keep the 5 divs? Maybe I should make just one initial div tag, then make 5 class tags for the bodies. Would that be possible? Any and all help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. I went to the site and everything appears normal when I resize my browser window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not benefiting at all from making those images backgrounds of `<div>`s, and you're probably compounding that trouble by using positioning. Without recoding the whole thing for you, here's a 'better' approach:

CSS

```
<style>
    /* Make your main components all the same width, and center them within <body>. Their heights will expand as needed */
    #header, #cssmenu, #content { width:1024px; margin:0 auto }
    #cssmenu { ... } /* Looks like what you have will work fine */
    /* #body1/2/3/4....not needed */
</style>
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="cssmenu">...</div>
    <!-- img elements exist for a reason :-) don't be scared -->
    <div id="content"><img src="body2.jpg"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Do I want to put <style>css content here</style> in <head></head> or in a css document?

Comment: Best practice is a linked .css file

Comment: I hope you don't mind, I shot you an e-mail via your site. I had a few more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, Theres a lot to learn to building websites. so first, its a good effort. Your issue is you have positioned everything by an absolute value of pixels, so there will always be a margin on the left no matter what size the screen is. Rather than talk you through eveything you can do better i'll give you this instead.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bCgUb/19/)

its a layout just like yours, but simple and mid aligned. its smaller so you can see it in the example. I will encourage you to play and break and fix it to learn how the different properties effect the layout. Also look for tutorials on HTML and CSS.